# Trying to join a two-dimensional array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, implode

I'm trying to convert a two-dimensional array to a string in order to store it in the localStorage array. However, there is something wrong with this code I cannot identify:

```
for(x in array) {
    if(array[x] instanceof Array) {
        array[x] = array[x].join("`");
    }
}
var string = array.join("@");
localStorage[key] = string;
```

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

As for what's wrong, by multidimensional array I mean array[0][1] etc.
When input into localStorage, all the 'string' is reduced to is @, implying on the other side of the @ there are still arrays.

Comment: what is the something that is wrong? surely, you ucan say what your input is, what you expected, and what the undesired output is?

Comment: On a sidenote, you might want to consider using JSON.stringify instead of custom seperators for your purpos.

Comment: @Thomas - At the time of writing, JSON.stringify was not available in all the browsers (specifically, not in the stable build of Chrome). Now, I would use that, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what is the something that is wrong? surely, you ucan say what your input is, what you expected, and what the undesired output is?

At least, if `array` is indeed an array, you should not use a `for..in loop`. That's for objects. Just use a

```
for (var i=0, l=array.length; i<l; i++){
    if (array[i] instanceof Array){
        array[i] = array[i].join("`");
    }
}
```

Comment: for..in loops are ok to use for Arrays, it's not only for objects..as long as you use 'hasOwnProperty'.

Answer (score 32):

Nowadays this is as simple as:

```
[[1,2],[3,4]].map(e => e.join(':')).join(';'); // 1:2;3:4
```

Answer (score 2):

[`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) is now standard in modern browsers. You can use it to "stringify" (convert to a JSON string) and "parse" convert from a JSON string.

You can use the `JSON.stringify` function to convert your 2D array to JSON and stick it in `localStorage`. Then you can use `JSON.parse` to convert it back to an array.

```
var my2DArray = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]];
var stringified = JSON.stringify(my2DArray);
localStorage[key] = stringified;

var backToOriginal = JSON.parse(localStorage[key]);
```

Comment: Back in January 2010, JSON wasn't available as such in stable browsers. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't have two dimensional arrays. It has only ragged arrays. Your code works for me for an appropriate input:

```
array = [[1,2],[3,4]];
for(x in array) {
    if(array[x] instanceof Array) {
        array[x] = array[x].join("`");
    }
}
var string = array.join("@");
alert(string);
```

Output:

```
1`2@3`4
```

Could you show us what input you are using and what output you get?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine for me, testing in Firefox.

Is it failing in a specific browser?

```
var array = [
["a","b"],
["c","d","e"]];
for(x in array) {
    if(array[x] instanceof Array) {
        array[x] = array[x].join("`");
    }
}
var string = array.join("@");
console.log(string);
```